# How to use an array that was returned from a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array, return

I created a method that reads a bunch of numbers from a file, takes the first two numbers to be the row and the column length of the array, then converts the rest of them into integers and places the integers into the two dimensional array:

```
public static int[][] fillArray(String myFile){
    //uses another class to create a text field
    TextFileInput in = new TextFileInput(myFile); 

    int[][] filledArray;
    //uses a method in class TextInputFile to read a line then go to the next line
    String line = in.readLine();
    //int i=0;
    int row, col;
    row = Integer.parseInt(line);
    line = in.readLine();
    col = Integer.parseInt(line);
    filledArray = new int[row][col];
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<col; j++){
            line = in.readLine();
            filledArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
    }
    return filledArray;
}
```

My question is how would I access the individual elements in my multidementional array `filledArray`? As in, how would I print what's in `filledArray[1][3]` or add `filledArray[1][3]+filledArray[2][3]` in the main method?

Comment: Oh no, how do I close this question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just store the returned array in a local one

```
public static void main(String[]args){
  int[][]array = fillArray("fileName"); // call the method
  // traverse the array using a loop

  for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
     System.out.println(a[i][j]); // do something with elements 

 }
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was supposed to be that simple. Can you explain to me why a returned filledArray can be stored in a local array? Is it because filledArray is simply a reference to a memory block containing the array, and assigning the reference to a local array assigns all the values to that array? I am sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: @Chase fillArray returns an array, right? how to capture the returned value? we have to store it in a local variable of the same type.Simply

Comment: @Chase `fillArray` returns a reference to an array that is stored on the heap (this is what the keyword `new` does for you). When you access the values in the array from `static void main`, you are accessing the same memory locations on the heap that were used in `fillArray`.

Answer (score 2):

The fillArray method returns a *reference* to the array that it creates. All you have to do is assign a local variable to this in your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[][] arr = fillArray("file.txt");

   System.out.println(arr[1][3]);

   System.out.println(arr[1][3] + arr[2][3]);
}
```

You access individual elements by using indices in your array, for example `arr[4][2]`. Just be careful you don't generate an *IndexOutOfBoundsException*, which is why it's a good idea to check the array length in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You would take the result of `fillArray(...)`, store it in a variable and then do stuff with it.

E.g.

```
int[][] filled=fillArray("file.txt");
System.out.println(filled[1][3]);
System.out.println(filled[1][3]+filled[2][3]);
```